# No Shell after login message after SSH to VM

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, virtualbox, openssh

As the title says, I don't have shell on the VM after I ssh into it

[image]

The machine is on the Virtual Box with Port Forwarding on port 22 enabled. What's the reason of this? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `ssh` without `-T`.

From the `man` of `ssh`:

> -T Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.

So, you won't have a shell if you call `ssh -T`.

For example I executed it with `-T`:

```
root@localhost:~# ssh test@localhost -p 1337 -T
test@localhost's password:
^C
```

and without `-T`:

```
root@localhost:~# ssh test@localhost -p 1337   
test@localhost's password:
$
```

Comment: Well looks like it worked xd, idk why I had -T flag, probably used it to another issue with ssh which I solved. Looks like I played myself. Thank you so much for your answer!